# Development Platform / Emulator to test and debug HTML5 mobile game

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio-2010, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a game using three.js, HTML5 and JQuery Mobile. I will eventually use PhoneGap in order to compile my code into an app which I will upload to Google Play and Apple App store. What I need is some kind of IDE that allows me to test the game while in development on my mobile phone, so I can see how it works as an app. I don't know if just checking it on the mobile phone browser or an emulator is the best way to do it. I want to know exactly how my app will run on, let's say, and Android device so I can make sure that when it is deployed to the store it will work as intended.

I prefer something for visual studio, but any other IDE/Development Platform that have a good way to emulate or even directly run my code on my actual Android device would be great. I want to be able to test the game to see hot it works with gestures, so being able to run it on my mobile phone would be the better solution.

Again, I prefer something for Visual Studio, but any other IDE / Emulator would be fine too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the best tool to debug a phonegap application is Ripple, ie a Chrome extension that emulates phonegap's javascript APIs:
http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/08/10/introducing-phonegap-emulation/

Some APIs are not covered yet but it's still a huge time saver. And you can use Chrome's developer tools to debug your javascript code. 
Ripple clearly does not replace tests on a real device.

<del>Instead of using the url suggested in the article (http://emulate.phonegap.com?your_url_here) I open

    http://localhost/my_project/ 

(which points to the www/assets/index.html file of my project. I use apache but any web server is fine) in Chrome and then I enable ripple (right click | Emulator | Enable).</del>

**Ripple has changed!** It's not a chrome extension anymore. Detailed info at http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn

Another post very useful from the same blog is http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/7/Using-Grunt-to-automatically-build-your-PhoneGapCordova-projects

 This will explain how to use grunt to save time while using ripple.

For the application development I second Gajotres answer, I use eclipse as well.

Answer (score 1):

First lets start from Visual Studio, no you cant use it, in theory yes, but in practice no. While you can create hybrid android applications in Visual Studio with [**VSNomad**](http://vsnomad.com/how-works.html) you would need to pay 25/35 USD monthly to be able to use it. And even then you will not be able to use Phonegap plugins. If money and plugin non existence is not a problem for you then go with this solution.

In any other case lets look at other solutions. Because you are using windows platform lets discuss compatible solutions.

Currently best Windows IDE for Android app development (doesn't matter native or hybrid apps) is [**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/). Excellent IDE if you don't mind Java in the background. But you don't need to install everything manually, Google has taken care of this. All you need to do is go to this [**link**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) and download/unpack Eclipse prebuilt with Android SDK. After the installation you will only need to update/install additional Android versions.

To do that:

> open Eclipse -->  click Window --> Android SDK manager and download
>   needed versions.

From there you can create new Android project (follow **[this](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.com/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html)** tutorial, it is an excellent one). Basically you will create everything like you are creating a Phonegap app but without Phonegap stuff (everything is described in tutirial).

From here you can test your app on a emulator or if you have and Android mobile phone ypu can test it on your phone directly (this is what you need). One more step before you can use your mobile phone as a test machine. You will need to do some changes on your phone.

1. Allow installation of 3rd party apps (apps not found in Google play store), tutorial can be found **[here](http://droidlessons.com/how-to-install-non-market-third-party-apps-on-android/)**.
2. You mobile phone must have USB debugging mode turned on, tutorial can be found **[here](http://dottech.org/87439/how-to-unlock-usb-debugging-mode-on-android-4-2-jelly-bean-and-higher-guide/)**.
3. Mobile phone drivers must be installed on a computer (for example if you have a Samsung phone you will need to install [Kies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Kies) software)

Comment: For those with a Samsung phone (e.g. Galaxy Nexus i9250): you do **not** need to install the *Kies* software which includes unnecessary extra tools. Just google for `[phone name] driver` and you'll find some forum posts which have a link for downloading a driver (and only *that*!).

Answer (score 0):

I have found Eclipse to be pretty poor when I had to deal with web technologies such as HTML and Javascript. Remember that those are the main technologies to work when using Phonegap/Cordova.

If you don't need much support on the native side of the application (Java on Android, Objective-C on iOS, etc), I'd recommend Brackets, Sublime Text 2 or WebStorm as the top IDEs for html5 stack. One could even use some of the recent online IDEs integrated with github.

Now if you do need the native support, I'd go with Intellij IDEA for Android (or you could mix Eclipse with any of the above web IDEs). You don't have much of a choice on iOS, but AppCode could ease the pain of having to deal with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try weinre (WEb INspector REmote).
It's a web inspector (like firebug) working with mobile emulators web browser.

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Supports iOS, Android and WP.